# How to merge two trained incpton_v3 models with difrent number of class for multiple output?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

example:

1. `inceptionv3_model1` with 10  classes (banana, orange, grape...)
2. `inceptionv3_model2` with 3 classes (expired, note expired, normal)

I need to merge this two models to get multiple output result. for example expired banana or normal banana...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should retrain the model. It sounds like you have 2 labels for each sample, the class [banana, orange, grape, etc], AND the state [expired, not expired, normal] (though I don't see the difference between normal and not expired).

The most straightforward way to deal with this is to use multi-task learning. Read up in more detail here:

http://ruder.io/multi-task/

Your inputs should be `data`, `label_type`, `label_state`, into an inceptionv3 model (the same one you're using).

Now take the cost function you're using for each of the current models. Something like this:

```
cost_type = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels=label_type, logits=logits_type)
cost_state = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels=label_state, logits=logits_state)
```

Or use whatever loss function you're currently using. Now define a cumulative loss function as:

```
cost = cost_type + cost_state
```

Since those are both cross entropy (classification) loss there won't be any issue of scale to worry about. Minimize `cost` and you should get a network trained to produce both outputs. It often happens that this network will outperform the individual networks on their respective tasks.

You will need to create two output layers for each of the cost functions above. Each of those layers can connect to the same layer. Let me know if that's not clear and I'll elaborate.

Comment: Its 100% clear @David Parks, thank you very much for your answer. if i may ask, please let me know if you have/know any work similar to this so that i could use it as starting point. iam prety much new to AI world. much respect!

Comment: It's surprisingly simple to do this. You could practice with some very simple tutorial examples. I always recommend these tutorials, they're very clearly and simply written and a great place to get your feed wet with this technique before applying it to a larger model with more moving parts. https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples